# C++ DLL calling a function implemented in the consuming application

Tags: c++, dll, function-pointers, virtual-functions

How to call a post-implemented function (e.g., function pointers or virtual functions implemented in the consuming application) with a complex return type from a DLL function?

I tried the following scheme but got errors.

Test.h:

```
#ifdef _DLL_IMPL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)  
#else  
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)  
#endif
typedef string (*test)(void);
extern DLL_EXPORT test __test;
DLL_EXPORT int launch();
```

Test.cpp:

```
#define _DLL_IMPL
#include "Test.h"
test __test = 0;
int launch()
{
    string a = __test();
    return 0;
}
```

And the consuming application goes like:

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Test.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Test.lib")
string test_impl()
{
    string a = "test";
    return a;
}
int main(int args, char** argv)
{
    __test = &test_impl;
    return launch();
}
```

And I got a subsequent error message:

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in TestRun.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
TestRun.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while TestRun.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

I don't know what exactly was going on. Error also occurred when I tried a return type of a char pointer, which would be created in the consuming application using a new operator and would be freed in a DLL function using a delete[] operator.

Can someone explain the reason why the error happens and suggest me some solution to this scheme? Thank you!

Comment: I don't believe you can new in the app and delete in the dll.  That would cause heap corruption.

Comment: Yes, I also believe that's the reason why it does not work. I don't really know how to implement the scheme I described (i.e., calling a function implemented in the app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing C++ objects between exe and dll is really not a good idea, more so if the object is based on a template class and/or has inlined methods, and even more so if the object allocates memory internally. If you need that kind of interface between your application and the library then I recommend that you switch your dll to a static library, then you'll avoid most issues.

If you need to keep the dll as a dll, then I recommend that you only pass native types between exe and dll. In your example, switching all the usages of `string` to `char*` will likely address the crashes.

Also take good advice from Jim Rhodes and declare an explicit calling convention, even if you found that that was not the problem in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a calling convention mismatch. Maybe string test_impl() should be string __stdcall test_impl().

Comment: Thanks to your attention, but it seems not solving this problem. I tried to modify:

Test.h:

    typedef string ( __stdcall  *test)(void);

Main.cpp:

    string __stdcall  test_impl()...

Error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You very likely are linking with different versions of the C runtime libraries, preventing shared heap use.  Make sure that both the app and dll are linked with the same 'flavor' (dynamic or static) of the C runtime libraries - if you aren't sure which one to pick, set them both to dynamic.

See also [Strange problems with new/delete in an app that uses my DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302008/strange-problems-with-new-delete-in-an-app-that-uses-my-dll).

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to export/import is not clear. You export test_impl from main.cpp and import launch in main.cpp from test.cpp

Anyway, you should probably export also classes (std::string).

The following code works perfectly:

```
//test.cpp
typedef __declspec(dllimport)    std::string        (*test)(void); 

    extern __declspec(dllexport)  test __test;

    test __test = 0; 

extern __declspec(dllexport)    int launch() {      std::string a = __test();     
std::cout << a << std::endl ; 
return 0; } 

// main.cpp 
typedef __declspec(dllexport)    std::string        (*test)(void); 
extern __declspec(dllimport)  test __test;
extern __declspec(dllimport)  test __test;

__declspec(dllimport)  int launch(); 

__declspec(dllexport) 
std::string test_impl() {  
    std::string a = "test";   
    return a; } 

int main(int args, char** argv) {  
    __test = &test_impl;    
    return launch(); }
```

Check however that both projects are compiled with the same model (/MTd, /Mt)

Comment: I tried your code, however, the error remains the same: `This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in TestRun.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.` I think @Miguel might be right and I compile my code into a static library and it works. My main purpose is to hide my code and let someone else to implement the interface that I provided and then integrate the whole system. I don't really care whether it's a static library or a DLL as a result. Nonetheless, I still want to figure out the reason why it goes wrong when it's compiled into a DLL.